# Logistic Regression Problem

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

You are testing a new drug and have gathered binary data on whether the drug performed its desired effects. From the control trial, $102$ people saw improvement with a placebo and $241$ did not. With the drug, $67$ people saw improvement and 82 did not. What is the odds ratio of these results?

My solution is that $a = 102, c = 241$ for placebo and $b = 67, d = 82$ for drug, odds ratio should be $a*d/b*c = 102*82/67*241 = 8364/16147$, but it didn't seem to be right, can anyone tells what went wrong? Much appreciated

Comment: I would have done $\dfrac{67/82}{102/241}$, i.e. putting the odds for the treatment on top.  This give the reciprocal of your result

Comment: Traditionally you would put the odds for the treatment group in the numerator when taking the ratio as noted by Henry. So an effective treatment has an OR > 1. But you also need to be careful if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Henry, that works